# Iterating over JSONObject in GWT JSNI

Tags: json, gwt, iteration, jsni

I have a native method which should iterate over the JSONObject. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
public native void foo(JSONObject c)/*-{
    var keys = c.@com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject::keySet()();

    for ( var k : keys ){
        alert(k); // this does not fire up. no error in console :(
    }
}-*/;
```

Also, is there a way convert Java `Map` type to `JSONObject`?

Any hint would be much appreciated! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSONObject#keySet` returns a `Set`, which is an object *wrapping* a JS array (in prod mode; in DevMode it's the standard `java.util.Set` from your JVM.

So, either use plain Java:

```
Set<String> keys = c.keySet();
for (String key : keys) {
  Window.alert(key); // or call a JSNI method here if you need?
}
```

or first extract the underlying `JavaScriptObject` and then you can use a JS `for…in`:

```
var o = c.@com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject::getJavaScriptObject()();
for (var k in o) {
  if (o.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    alert(k);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like:

```
for (var k in c) {
  if (c.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    alert(k+":"+c[k]);
  }
}
```

I my memory does not fail, I think this code works...

About your second question, if your entity is a Java-GWT valid entity, you can use [Autobeans](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean#JSON_structures) for getting the JsonObject.